# Is it possible to extend an existing Twig (in Symfony 2) function without creating a new one?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is it possible to extend a Twig (Symfony2) function without creating a new one?

So if I wanted to extend the 'url' or 'path' Twig functions, could I do it?

I can't see that this is possible and think the only option is to create my own function.

So a simple, "no you must create your own function" or "yes, this is possible" will do (and maybe a link as I can't see how to do it anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I am pretty sure you can extend the existing functionality. I did not test this but I think it should work.

For example the Symfony2 Router Extension for Twig:

Create your own class which extends and changes functionality:

```
Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension
```

put twig.extension.routing.class in your paramters.yml with the created class Namespace to overwrite it

```
parameters:
    # [ ... ]
    twig.extension.routing.class: Company\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig\Extension\RoutingExtension
```